# Adobe Campaign Standard - Avoid sending zero byte files

Tags: adobe, workflow, acs, segment

I have a requirement to send data to a server. A Workflow has been written in ACS to query data and then send it to a server.I have used segmentation before sending data to a server but in case of zero results also it sends data forward, causing a blank file to be generated and sent to external server.
Please suggest how to stop sending zero result file.

Answer (score 0):

As updated on Adobe forum,it is an ACS product limitation for now. There is an active Enhancement Request for it.
[Reference](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2508553)